# Get text with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

i'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to get text from a webpage.
The page i need to manipulate is something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1>HELLO</h1>
Hello, world!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to get the `h1` element and the text that has no tags.
to get the `h1` i use this code:

```
$html = file_get_html("remote_page.html");
foreach($html->find('#content') as $text){
echo "H1: ".$text->find('h1', 0)->plaintext;
}
```

But the other text?
I also tried this into the foreach but i get the full text:

```
$text->plaintext;
```

but it returned also the `H1` tag...

Comment: Why do you expext the `plaintext` member to return something else?

Comment: i need only the 'Hello, World!' part, is it possible?

Comment: I guess so, but I can't recommend Simple HTML DOM Parser, but just [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument). It would be `->nodeValue` then.

Comment: I'm with the same problem, I want to extract the text after a tag that is not within tags...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$text->find('text',2);` gets what you're looking for, however I'm not sure how well that will work when the amount of text nodes is unknown. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply strip html tags using [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
<?php
strip_tags($input, '<br>');
?>
```

Comment: Why would you exclude the `<br>` tag? The OP said that all tags need stripped.

Comment: you can leave that blank.

Answer (score 0):

Use strip tags, as @Peachy pointed out. However, passing it a second argument `<br>` means string will *ignore* `<br>` tags, which is unnecessary. In your case,

```
<?php
    strip_tags($text);
?>
```

would work as you'd like, given that you are only selecting content in the `content` id.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
echo "H1: ".$text->find('h1', 0)->innertext;
```